# Emails are not sent out after deploying to Lamba function

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, nodemailer

I'm using Nodemailer and SES to send out mails from my application, it works perfectly locally but doesn't work once I deploy to Lambda function, it returns with a "Endpoint request timed out" error message after it exceeds the 30 seconds API gateway time limit.
Note: The Lambda function has all the permissions required to send out SES mails.

I thought SES was the problem and I decided to use gmail instead, I got the same result. Checking my cloudwatch logs I find this error:

```
2022-11-16T06:54:23.547Z    6d967bf2-0837-4bd8-ae5f-011842656d15    INFO    Error: Connection timeout
    at SMTPConnection._formatError (/var/task/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:790:19)
    at SMTPConnection._onError (/var/task/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:776:20)
    at Timeout.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:235:22)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:559:17)
    at processTimers (node:internal/timers:502:7) {
  code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  command: 'CONN'
}
```

Here's my function for sending out the mails, I have modified it so many times, I thought I was the one not structuring it properly.

```
const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport ({
  service: 'gmail',
  host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
  port: 587,
  secure: true,
  auth: {
    user: config.REACT_APP_EMAIL,
    pass: config.REACT_APP_EMAIL_PASS,
  },
});

const sendOutMail = async (receiver, emailSubject, body) => {
  return transporter.sendMail({
        from: config.REACT_APP_EMAIL,
        to: receiver,
        subject: emailSubject,
        text: body,
        html: '<div> ' + emailSubject + '</div>',
      })
    .then( results => {
        console.log("Success:", results);
        return true
    })
    .catch ( error => {
        console.log("Error:", error);
        return false
    })

}
```

All modifications of my function works locally, but none works after I deploy

Comment: To confirm, your Lambda does NOT run on a VPC? And how long does it take until it timed out?

Comment: Yes it is run on a VPC and then it takes about 30 seconds to timeout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your lambda function runs inside a VPC, make sure you have internet access on this VPC. Otherwise you need to create a VPC Endpoint for SES so that your lambda can make that API call.

Here is the documentation for reference:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/send-email-set-up-vpc-endpoints.html